# Not getting Custom Error Message in REST

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, wcf, rest

I am developing a REST API.
Below is my code:

In IService.vb

```
<OperationContract(),
        WebGet(UriTemplate:="/DCU/{ClientID}",
               RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Xml,
               ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Xml,
               BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)>
    Function GetAllData(ByVal ClientID As String) As List(Of Data)
```

In Service.vb

```
    Friend Class Service
        Implements IService

    Public Function GetAllData(ByVal intClientID As String) As System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Data) Implements ILightingGaleService.GetAllDCUs
            Dim lstdata As New List(Of Data)()        
            If IsNumeric(intClientID) Then
            Else
                Throw New FaultException("Invalid Client ID")
            End If
    End Class
```

In Web.Config file

```
<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
```

I am getting

Request Error:The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details.

When I am passing a String value in Client ID. Though I have implemented FaultExpcetion i never get "Invalid Client ID" message in POSTMAN or Web Client.

Can anyone help me on how can I get my custom message on POSTMAN or web client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by implementing below:

I generated a class CustomError:

```
<DataContract> _
Public Class CustomError
    Public Sub New(strError As String, strErrorDesc As String, strErrorCode As Long)
        ErrorInfo = strError
        ErrorDetails = strErrorDesc
        ErroCode = strErrorCode
    End Sub

    <DataMember> _
    Public Property ErrorInfo() As String
        Get
            Return m_ErrorInfo
        End Get
        Private Set(value As String)
            m_ErrorInfo = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_ErrorInfo As String

    <DataMember> _
    Public Property ErrorDetails() As String
        Get
            Return m_ErrorDetails
        End Get
        Private Set(value As String)
            m_ErrorDetails = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_ErrorDetails As String

    <DataMember> _
    Public Property ErroCode() As Long
        Get
            Return m_ErroCode
        End Get
        Private Set(value As Long)
            m_ErroCode = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_ErroCode As Long
End Class
```

In Service.vb

Friend Class Service
        Implements IService

```
Public Function GetAllData(ByVal intClientID As String) As System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Data) Implements ILightingGaleService.GetAllDCUs
        Dim lstdata As New List(Of Data)()        
        If IsNumeric(intClientID) Then
        Else
            Dim ExceptionError As New CustomError("Client ID not found.", "The Client ID is not found in system.", HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            Throw New WebFaultException(Of CustomError)(ExceptionError, HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        End If
End Class
```

So this will generate a Webexception for my Custom Error Message which I wanted to display on my Client Application:
Now on my client application I used below

```
Catch ex As WebException
            Dim strError = New StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd()
            lblErrorMsg.Text = strError
End Try
```

Hope this helps to someone.